# How does remote internet server send packets to local IP?

Tags: networking

I don't understand basic routing concept. Namely, how does remote internet server construct packet when sending it to my local IP address.

Consider real life example. I am connected to the Internet through my provider. Provider gives me and other clients ip addresses from private range `10.100.251.1-255`. Suppose that provider gives me ip address `10.100.251.4` dynamically. I wan't open `stackoverflow.com(151.101.65.69)` site in browser. Heap of gateways exists between me and `stackoverflow.com`. Last gateway that connects me with external Internet is `85.112.122.13`. When I open `stackoverflow.com` in browser my computer constructs packet with destination address is `151.101.65.69`, looks up gateway for this address in routing table and sends packet to gateway. This first gateway does the same and forwards my packet to second gateway, and so on until packet arrives to last gateway `85.112.122.13`. Let suppose for simplicity that `85.112.122.13` sends may packet to `stackoverflow.com` directly. Now `stackoverflow.com` gets my packet and wants to send me response. But I don't understand how does it do this. All that `stackoverflow.com` can get from packet is source ip address (`10.100.251.4`). But this ip address is private and no routers in the internet knows where to send packets for this. Where am I wrong and how internet server sends response to private ip address?

Comment: You forgot to consider NAT, I guess.

Comment: @DanielB NAT is precisely the answer to this question, that OP seems to not know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of those gateways – usually the 1st or 2nd – is configured to **overwrite** the source IP address of all outgoing packets; it "masquerades" the private addresses using its own public address. (This is known as [source NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).)

So `stackoverflow.com` just sends replies to the NAT gateway's global address and doesn't know your private IP address at all. (And if you check various ["what is my IP"](https://ipv6-test.com/) websites, you will always see a public address belonging to that gateway.)

The same router also keeps track of every connection, so whenever it receives a packet to its global address, it can look up which host originally initiated the connection and translate the destination address back to the original private address. (In other words, it performs stateful NAT – the information is kept in a "state table" or "conntrack table".)